# Unnest hits and Unnesting session scoped custom dimension BigQuery code filter

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to filter a funnel based on users who have certain custom dimension values. Sadly, the custom dimension in question is session-scoped and not hit-based, so i cannot use hits.customDimensions in this particular query. What is the best way to do this and achieve the desired result?
Find my progress so far:

```
    #standardSQL
    SELECT 
       SUM((SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE page.pagePath = '/one - Page' LIMIT 1)) One_Page,
       SUM((SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE page.pagePath = '/one - Page') AND page.pagePath = '/two - Page' LIMIT 1)) Two_Page,
       SUM((SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE page.pagePath = '/one - Page') AND page.pagePath = '/three - Page' LIMIT 1)) Three_Page,
       SUM((SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE page.pagePath = '/one - Page') AND page.pagePath = '/four - Page' LIMIT 1)) Four_Page
    FROM `xxxxxxx.ga_sessions_*`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS h,
    UNNEST(customDimensions) AS cusDim
    WHERE
      _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190320' AND '20190323'
      AND h.hitNumber = 1
      AND cusDim.index = 6
      AND cusDim.value IN ('60','70)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Segmentation with Custom Dimensions

You can filter for sessions based on conditions in custom dimensions. Simply write a sub-query counting cases of interest and set to ">0". Example for sample data:

```sql
SELECT
  fullvisitorid,
  visitstarttime,
  customdimensions
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170505` t
WHERE
  -- there should be at least one case with index=4 and value='EMEA' ... you can use your index and desired value
  -- unnest() turns customdimensions into table format, so we can apply SQL to this array
  (select count(1)>0 from unnest(customdimensions) where index=4 and value='EMEA')
limit 100
```

You comment the WHERE statement to see all the data.

## Funnel

First you might want to get an overview of what is going on in your hits array:

```sql
SELECT
  fullvisitorid,
  visitstarttime,
  -- get an overview over relevant hits data
  -- select as struct feeds hits fields into a new array created by array()-function
  ARRAY(select as struct hitnumber, page from unnest(hits) where type='PAGE') hits
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170505` t
WHERE
  (select count(1)>0 from unnest(customdimensions) where index=4 and value='EMEA')
  and totals.pageviews>3
limit 100
```

Now that you made sure the data makes sense you can create a funnel array containing the hit numbers of the relevant steps:

```sql
SELECT
  fullvisitorid,
  visitstarttime,
  -- create array with relevant info
  -- cross join hit numbers from step pages to get all combinations so that we can check later which came after the other
  ARRAY(
    select as struct * from
    (select hitnumber as step1 from unnest(hits) where type='PAGE' and page.pagePath='/home') left join
    (select hitnumber as step2 from unnest(hits) where type='PAGE' and page.pagePath like '/google+redesign/%') on true left join
    (select hitnumber as step3 from unnest(hits) where type='PAGE' and page.pagePath='/basket.html') on true
    ) AS funnel
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170505` t
WHERE
  (select count(1)>0 from unnest(customdimensions) where index=4 and value='EMEA')
  and totals.pageviews>3
limit 100
```

Put this into a WITH statement for  more clarity and run your analysis by summarizing the corresponding cases:

```sql
WITH f AS (
  SELECT
    fullvisitorid,
    visitstarttime,
    totals.visits,
    -- create array with relevant info
    -- cross join hit numbers from step pages to get all combinations so that we can check later which came after the other
    ARRAY(
      select as struct * from
        (select hitnumber as step1 from unnest(hits) where type='PAGE' and page.pagePath='/home') left join
        (select hitnumber as step2 from unnest(hits) where type='PAGE' and page.pagePath like '/google+redesign/%') on true left join
        (select hitnumber as step3 from unnest(hits) where type='PAGE' and page.pagePath='/basket.html') on true
      ) AS funnel
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170505` t
  WHERE
    (select count(1)>0 from unnest(customdimensions) where index=4 and value='EMEA')
    and totals.pageviews>3
)

SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT fullvisitorid) as users,
  SUM(visits) as allSessions,
  SUM( IF(array_length(funnel)>0,visits,0) ) sessionsWithFunnelPages,
  SUM( IF( (select count(1)>0 from unnest(funnel) where step1 is not null ) ,visits,0) ) sessionsWithStep1,
  SUM( IF( (select count(1)>0 from unnest(funnel) where step1 is not null and step1<step2 ) ,visits,0) ) sessionsFunnelToStep2,
  SUM( IF( (select count(1)>0 from unnest(funnel) where step1 is not null and step1<step2 and step2<step3 and step1<step3) ,visits,0) ) sessionsFunnelToStep3
FROM f
```

Please test before using.

Comment: Absolutely brilliantly detailed solution Martin. Thank you for taking the time to put it together. I've got questions:  1. The figures returned in BQ are lower than the figures returned in GA by about 7%, I expected the figures to be higher in BQ, any ideas why that is?    2. If this funnel extends to say 14 steps, this part of the code:    where step1 is not null and step1<step2 and step2<step3 and step1<step3</pre>         has to be rewritten like so:      where step1 is not null and step1<step14 and step13<step14 and step1<step14 ??        3. How do we make this a user-based funnel.

Comment: 1. GA checks for page immediately followed by the next page, while this approach allows other pages in between funnel pages. 2. The comparisons are the funnel - make sure every step is followed by the other - maybe this can be optimized, 14 steps is a lot. 3. You need to array_concat_agg(hits) grouped by fullvisitorid before doing the calculation

Comment: Apologies for coming back to this Martin, still trying to wrap my head around how the comparisons work and if my 8-step funnel is structured correctly., if you can add two more steps to the subselect query (ie sessionsFunnelToStep4, sessionsFunnelToStep5) with some explanation as to exactly how they are supposed to work as the funnel progresses, it will prove to be extremely useful to me. Thank you very much Martin.

Comment: Just think mathematically - if you want a after b after c, then you need to make sure that a is smaller than b and b is smaller than c - but also that a is smaller than c! Because you can have two b's in a situation like b < c <  a < b ... which clearly fulfills a<b and b<c but is not what you want unless you check for a<c. Now add another step and you need to make even more comparisons ...

Comment: Thanks again Martin for your detailed response, I totally get it, with more steps comes more comparisons and could get a bit cluttered and complicated with a 12-step funnel for instance.  Great work with this Martin.

Comment: Hello Martin, any ideas why I get this error: "Array is larger than the maximum supported size of 128 MB. If the query uses the ARRAY or ARRAY_AGG functions, use a LIMIT clause to restrict the number of array elements."   when I add device category, channel grouping and increase the date range to about 5 months?, tried searching online for the reason for this but have not found any proper solution.